# arcgis 10.2 javascript api proxy printtask error

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing

when i invoke a printtask without the proxy, everything runs fine. But, when i use it, the invocation fails.

It seems that the cause is that the proxy is appending a double quote to the end of the url, so instead of sending

...Layout_Template=test

it sends

...Layout_Template=test"

Details:

- Java proxy v 1.0

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify which of the several possible proxies your are using (including the platform, the exact ArcGIS release, the web server, and the language), and include the proxy source.

Comment: please consider testing with the latest proxy code (1.1beta) and logging an issue in the resource -proxy repository on github